# MYSQL - insert if it does not exist but update only if it satisfy a criteria

Tags: mysql

I would like to get a help for a **mysql** ( using version 8 ) case.
I have following table

```
CREATE TABLE taskStatus (  task_id int NOT NULL,employee_id int NOT NULL, completed_on datetime DEFAULT NULL,task_status bit(1) NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (task_id,employee_id)) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

I would like to **insert** a row if `(task_id,employee_id)` does not exist but if it exists then it should **update** the row only **if task_status = 0**. By this way I want to ensure that if somebody set **task_status = 1** for a row then never change the **completed_on** value.
`INSERT INTO  …..  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`  will not work as it won’t take a where clause.
For me, **UPDATE** should happen only if  one column value satisfied a criteria but **INSERT** can happen without that condition.

I understood that I could do it using  multiple queries but I have to do it for lot of rows.
My understanding is that if I can do it in a single query then I can run it as a batch. If I do it in multiple query then I can not do it as batch and
whole thing may be too slow.

Could someone please suggest  some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) statement like ethis:

```
INSERT INTO taskStatus(task_id, employee_id, completed_on, task_status) VALUES
(?, ?, ?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    completed_on = VALUES(completed_on),
    task_status = CASE WHEN task_status THEN task_status ELSE VALUES(task_status) END;
```

The `CASE` expression will prevent to update `task_status` if it is already `1`.
If you also want `completed_on` not to be updated if `task_status` is `1`, use a similar `CASE` expression for it too:

```
completed_on = CASE WHEN task_status THEN completed_on ELSE VALUES(completed_on) END
```

Replace the `?` placeholders with the values of the columns that you want to insert.